# Store element into another list

Tags: java, list, data-structures

Need little help. Working on my homework and I have to sort list using ArrayDeque. I can check first and last element.
I have a list, for example

```
int[] list = {6, 8, 7};
```

First element - 6 - will go into empty array, no problem with that.
Second element - 8 - will go at behind the 6, so we will have`[6,8]`, but then comes 7. Since I can't put it in front of the 6, and I cant put it behind 8. So I have to store 7 into some other list that I can later return. How do I do that? Any hint is welcome. 
Thanks.
(And sorry if this is something that has been asked before, but couldn't find the solution)

Comment: *sort list using ArrayDeque*. Why would anyone ever do that? Why not use `Arrays.sort(list)`?

Comment: as you can read, it is homework

Comment: I understand that, but it doesn't make any sense to me. Sounds like "I need to go to the next city using a banana".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me clarify your constraints first. You can only:

- get the value of the first element
- remove the first element
- prepend before the first element
- get the value of the last element
- remove the last element
- append after the last element

An algorithm to add values from an array into a structure described above, using a stack:

- for each value in the array
- if the value is smaller than the first in the deck -> prepend
- else if the value is greater than the last in the deck -> append
- else if the value is closer to the first:

  - remove the first element and push on the stack repeatedly, as long as the first element is smaller
  - prepend the value to the deck
  - while the stack is not empty, pop from it and prepend to the deck
- else:

  - remove the last element and push on the stack repeatedly, as long as the last element is greater
  - append the value to the deck
  - while the stack is not empty, pop from it and append to the deck

If you are not allowed to use a stack, but you are allowed to use recursion, then you can use the call stack to the same end

Answer (score 0):

Something you could do is to store the int value at index x into a local variable and then traverse through the array seeing if there is a value lower than the currently stored value and if so that becomes the new lower value. When it finishes going through the array you can input that into the new array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayDeque<Integer> container = new ArrayDeque<>();
    ArrayDeque<Integer> container2 = new ArrayDeque<>();
    System.out.println("Please enter 10 number with space");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        container.add(sc.nextInt());
    }

    while (!isSorted(container.isEmpty()?container2:container)) {
        while (!container.isEmpty()) {
            int a = container.poll();
            if(container.peek()!=null && a<container.peek()){
                if(container2.peek()!=null && container2.peek()>container.peek()){
                    container2.addFirst(a);
                }else{
                    container2.addLast(a);
                }
            }else if(container.peek()!=null){
                if(container2.peek()!=null && container2.peek()>container.peek()){
                    container2.addFirst(container.poll());
                }else{
                    container2.addLast(container.poll());
                }
                container.addFirst(a);
            }else{
                container2.addLast(a);
            }
        }
        while (!container2.isEmpty()) {
            int a = container2.poll();
            if(container2.peek()!=null && a<container2.peek()){
                if(container.peek()!=null && container.peek()>container2.peek()){
                    container.addFirst(a);
                }else{
                    container.addLast(a);
                }
            }else if(container2.peek()!=null){
                if(container.peek()!=null && container.peek()>container2.peek()){
                    container.addFirst(container2.poll());
                }else{
                    container.addLast(container2.poll());
                }
                container2.addFirst(a);
            }else{
                container.addLast(a);
            }
        }
    }
    while (!container.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(container.poll());
    }
    System.out.println("---------------------------");
    while (!container2.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(container2.poll());
    }
}
  static boolean isSorted(ArrayDeque<Integer> con){
     boolean answer = true;
    for(int i=0;i<con.size()-1;i++){
        int a = con.poll();
        con.addLast(a);
        if(con.peek()!=null && a>con.peek()) answer= false;
    }
     con.addLast(con.poll());
    return answer;
}
```